# fork() and free all allocated memory

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory-management, fork

I'm writing a service (i.e. background process) and want to offer starting it via a shared library. That is, someone wanting to use the service would link to the shared library, call it's *start()* method, which would fork and return. The fork would then run the service.

The problem with this approach is that the service process now might have a lot of legacy allocated memory it actually doesn't need. Is there a way to get rid of that and have the forked process allocate its own stuff? I know about *exec()* of course, but the problem with that is

- that I need an executable which might not be in the location I expect it to be due to different operating system folder layouts
- that I'd have to cast all potential parameters to string to pass it as program arguments to *exec()*.

So basically, I'm looking for a way to call an arbitrary function *func()*  with some parameters that should run in a new process, and everything not passed into that function shouldn't be in the new process. Is there a way to achieve this or something similar?

Comment: This is generally unnecessary, as Linux uses a copy-on-write fork implementation so that the parent and child share the "copied" memory until the child modifies it.

Comment: What you want isn't really feasible. For instance, suppose the library uses stdio, and stdio has some allocated memory, you wouldn't want your "free all allocated memory" to free that. So what you really want is "free everything that's not needed any more", but how can a general-purpose function know what's not needed?

Comment: @RossRidge But you'd like to remove your reference to the copy, so it will all go away when the parent exits.

Comment: @RossRidge Also, "modifying" here also possibly means stuff like allocating new memory. This will change internal state of the user space allocator, possibly dirtying many pages with stuff allocated by the "calling" process.

Comment: @DanielJour Meh.  Any reasonably efficient allocator isn't going to modify "many pages" when allocating new memory.

Comment: @RosdRidge That greatly depends on the fragmentation when doing the fork. I'm also not talking about a single allocation, but rather many (done by the service). Due to possible fragmentation, they could end up in a lot of different pages, which contain (possibly a lot) of the data the "calling" process allocated.

Comment: @RossRidge It becomes unshared when either the parent or the child modifies it. In the extreme case, where the parent goes on to modify everything and the child just does its own stuff, you wind up with a copy of every page of memory the parent had allocated before the call to `fork`.

Comment: Your question is internally inconsistent. Either you can easily separate what is a parameter from what isn't or you can't. If you can't, then it's hopeless. How could you know what needs to be freed and what doesn't? If you can, then what's the problem with using `exec(/proc/self/exe)`? Just separate all the stuff you want to keep first (using shared memory, for example).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The problem with that would be that you'd execute the library's client program and not the library's server executable.

Comment: @thatotherguy True. You'd need the library API to include a function the application must call early in `main` that decides whether to return or not based on how the library was invoked, doing nothing if it's a normal invocation of the application. You can probably hook stuff before `main` if you must, but that's kind of ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting question that I sadly don't have a good answer for. I doubt any cleanup strategies like sbrk+close+munmap will reliably allow any libc based code to continue to function, so I'd try to make exec'ing better:

For any kind of exec based solution, you should be able to deep-copy data into shm to pass non-strings. This should take care of your second problem.

Here are some wild suggestions for your first issue:

1. Don't: just require that an executable is in PATH or a compile-time directory.

   This is transparent and follows the UNIX philosophy. An error message `Can't find myhelper in PATH` will not slow anyone down. Most tools depending on helper executables do this, and it's fine.
2. [Make your library executable](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2003-07/msg00232.html), and use that as your exec target. You can try finding its name with some kind of introspection, perhaps `/proc/self/maps` or whatever glibc offers.
3. Like above, but exec `python` or something you can be reasonably sure exists, and use a foreign pointer interface to run a function on your library.
4. As part of your build process, compile a tiny executable and include it as binary data in your library. Write it to `/tmp` and execute.

Out of these, I prefer the simplicity and transparency of #1, even if that's the most boring solution.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to rely on the PATH, because it is a security critical application and who knows where in the path an attacker might be able to place an alternative executable (e.g. ~/bin). One of the other points might work though. About the *exec* call, I'd be passing sensitive data into the executable (e.g. passwords). Will they then be visible in a call to *ps* if I pass them to *exec*?

Comment: You could always sanitize your path, people with write access to `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` already have the system pwned. Any data you pass by key through `shm_open` will have the permissions you specify in that call. Other users can not use `ps` or anything else to read it, even if they have the key.